# I copied a file on unix from say directory 1 to 2, and now im trying to rename said file but i keep getting an error ''no such file or directory''

Tags: linux, unix, mv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRcya.jpg)I had initially copied the file from my school directory to tmp, but now I cant find it in /tmp and I'm really confused cause it showed me that the file was copied

Answer (score 1):

if this is a unix system and /tmp is the system tmp folder, it is possible that file was purged.  many unix systems clean these folders up automatically every 10 to 30 days. /tmp is not a good place to store files.